# How can I show that the dot product scales up linearly with the norms of the underlying arguments?

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The title of this post is used to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality at the end of this excerpt from page 6 of Aggarwal's *Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning*:

[image: Page 6 excerpt]

EDIT: if vector x = (1,0), y = (3,4), and x_2 = (2^1/2,0), then while ||x_2|| = 2*||x||, y_dot_x is not 2*(y_dot_x_2)

Comment: It follows from the definition of the dot product, surely?

Comment: Well, the def of dot product used here is just the sum of the products of the components of the vectors. The def of the (squared) norm is the dot product of a vector with itself. I can't connect those two definitions well.

Comment: You seem to forget the square root in the definition of the norm. Of course $\Vert (\sqrt2,0) \Vert = \sqrt{2} \cdot \Vert(1,0) \Vert$.

Comment: Thank you Torsten. I wish you had made an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: $x \cdot y = (\|x\| {x \over \|x\|}) \cdot (\|y\| {y \over \|y\|}) = \|x\| \|y\| (  {x \over \|x\|} \cdot   {y \over \|y\|} ) $

Comment: @cumin: There you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, it follows right from the definition of the dot product that

$$\lvert ax \cdot y \rvert = \lvert x \cdot ay \rvert = \lvert a \rvert \lvert x \cdot y\rvert$$

for all scalars $a$ and vectors $x,y$. And also for the norm -- where you seem to have forgotten the square root in the definition $\Vert x \Vert := \sqrt{x \cdot x}$ -- we have

$$\Vert a x \Vert = \lvert a \rvert \Vert x \Vert$$

(in particular, e.g. $\Vert (\sqrt2, 0) \Vert = \sqrt2 \; \Vert (1,0) \Vert$). The claim in the source follows from these equalities as in user copper.hat's comment.